# Conflict of "addSelectionChangedListener" and "addDoubleClickListener" for TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

all related

With JFace `TableViewer`, I want to select some entry(e.g select a file) by single-click, and do some other operations(e.g go into a directory) by double-click.

Noticing `addSelectionChangedListener()` and `addDoubleClickListener()` via a webpage: http://javafact.com/2010/08/07/example-tableviewer-events/ , I add `SelectionChangedListener` and `DoubleClickListener` for my `TableViwer`, and find out: 
Either of the two listeners can work, but they can't work together - actually it's `DoubleClickListener` that can't work.

What's the problem? How I should implement listeners for  single-click and double-clicks? 
Any comments is appreciated.

About code: 
I created a tableViewer, and want to show filesystem structure. 
The expected behavior: User can double click a directory entry and tableViewer will show the structure of selected directory; user select a generic file by single-click. For other operations, warning message dialog will be shown.

The following is just code related with event handlers.

```
tableView.addSelectionChangedListener( new ISelectionChangedListener() {
public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
      IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) tableView.getSelection();  
      File selFile = (File) sel.getFirstElement();
      if(selFile != null){
    if (selFile.isDirectory()) {
       MessageDialog.openWarning(getShell(), "Warning", "You select a directory");
               return;
            }
    System.out.println("Selected : "+ selFile.getAbsolutePath());
    selectFileName = selFile.getAbsolutePath();

  }
    }
 });

 tableView.addDoubleClickListener( new IDoubleClickListener() {

@Override
public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent arg0) {
   Object selected;
   IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) tableView.getSelection();
   if (selection.size() != 1) return;
   selected = selection.getFirstElement();
   File file = (File) selected;
   if (file.isFile()) {
     MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(),"Warning", "You double-clicks a generic file");
     return;
   } 
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Clicked direcotry: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

    //applyNewDirectory(file);
  }
     }          
   });
```

Regards & Thanks from 
Sunzen

Comment: What do you mean with _"can't work"_?

Comment: I mean: the added listener responds to UI event as expected, e.g do some operation when user clicks an entry in TableViewer, do some other operation when user double-clicks an entry in TableViewer

Comment: If they do respond as expected, then where is the problem? Maybe posting some code would help to understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry for my input error. I meant to say that "the added listener does not responds to UI event as expected. Ok, I will post some code  -- it is not easy to post all the workable code.

Comment: Which of the two Listeners is executed? Did you try adding `System.out.println()`s to them?

Comment: are you trying to say only code of addSelectionChangedListener executes? primary reason for this is you are showing messagebox on selection change which prevent execution of doubleclick.

Comment: @shishir, I am showing a tooltip on the single click which is preventing the doubleclick. How can I solve the issue provided that I need to show the tooltip on single click?

Answer (score 0):

(prolog: still working with JFace/SWT here, so this might be of interest to someone)

The problem is that the API allows you to do this, but it does not work (oh SWT...).
You cannot have both listeners on the TableView, as the SelectionChangedListener will always grab the click and consume the event.

The solution is to attach the SelectionChangedListener to the underlying *table*, and the DoubleClickListener to the *TableViewer*.
This way you can have both, e.g.:

```
table.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener(...));
tableViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener(...));
```